# Я не могу изменять параметры камеры в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет. Я столкнулся с проблемой я не могу менять параметры камеры. На самой камере весит компонент CinemachineBrain. Помогите пж.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы изменять параметры камеры с `CinemachineBrain` вам нужно менять параметры не через камеру, а через виртуальную камеру к которой привязана ваша камера[image: скриншот]